# How to capture anchor clicks in datatable after paging or sorting

Tags: datatables

The problem I have is I want to capture all the anchor clicks within a jquery-datatable.  After initializing the datatable, I can capture the anchor clicks on page 1 of the data.  After the user changes pages of the datatable, I can't capture the anchor clicks any more.  How can I capture all anchor clicks on all pages?

Here is a link jsfiddle that shows the loading of the datatable.  On the first page, I can capture the anchor clicks, but on the other pages I can not.

http://jsfiddle.net/zn5u2ncp/

I am using the following code after loading my datatable to capture the anchor clicks.  This only works on page 1 of the datatable.  After the user changes pages, my capture of anchor clicks does not work any more.

```
$("#contactsearchpanellist").dataTable({"ordering":false});

$("#contactsearchpanellist a").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert('table click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind `tbody` for click events,like this

```
$("#contactsearchpanellist tbody").on("click",function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert('table click');
});
```

otherwise ,in your case bindings to `a` tags lost because tags recrates after sorting\pagging\filtering ,
here working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtdaLodm/).